# Efficient method of extracting a point from a 3D plane

Tags: math, 3d, mathematical-optimization, plane

I've come across this method of extracting a location from a 3D plane.

I've tested this and it works correctly, but for such a primitive operation, I was wondering if there was a, more efficient method in common practice.

```
void position_from_plane(float r_co[3], const float p[4])
{
    const float p_len_sq = p[0]*p[0] + p[1]*p[1] + p[2]*p[2];
    const float d = (-p[3] / p_len_sq) - 1.0f;

    r_co[0] = p[0] + p[0]*d;
    r_co[1] = p[1] + p[1]*d;
    r_co[2] = p[2] + p[2]*d;
}
```

---

*Note: this simply offsets the plane's direction component to find a point on a plane, it could of course return a point somewhere else on the plane and still be a correct answer, offsetting the planes orientation is just the most direct way to find this point.*

Comment: You know, it would help if you were to describe what your arguments actually mean. I take it that `r_co` is to receive the output, while `p` describes the plane as `p[0]*x + p[1]*y + p[2]*z + p[3] = 0`. But the sign of `p[3]` in particular is not that obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks good. You can shorten it somewhat to this:

```
void position_from_plane(float r_co[3], const float p[4])
{
    const float d = -p[3] / (p[0]*p[0] + p[1]*p[1] + p[2]*p[2]);
    r_co[0] = p[0]*d;
    r_co[1] = p[1]*d;
    r_co[2] = p[2]*d;
}
```

You could get slightly shorter code if you were to intersect one of the coordinate axes with your plane. But you'd pay for that by needing a case distinction, which I'd rather avoid. Unless you can guarantee that the plane won't be parallel to one of the coordinate axes, that is.

Comment: @ideasman42: You ask about a way to simplify your code, and then I suggest such a way, and you go ahead and paste that into your question. Doing so makes my answer seem more pointless than it is. Please leave questions which have ben answered in a state where those answers still make sense. If someone has an idea for further simplification, I'm sure he'll post even if your question doesn't contain my fix. I'll revert your edit to the question for this reason.